# Mounting a RAID array on Debian Wheezy

Tags: raid, mount, debian-wheezy

I've got a pair of 1TB drives on my Debian fileserver set to RAID 1 using a PCI controller, but it doesn't want to mount them.

If I do a `blkid` the drive doesn't show up, but I know (from using `cfdisk /dev/sdb` to create a partition) that the drives are working.

`lshw -class disk -class storage` gives me the following info about the array:

```
  *-storage
   description: SATA controller
   product: 88SE9123 PCIe SATA 6.0 Gb/s controller
   vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: scsi6
   logical name: scsi13
   version: 11
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list rom emulated
   configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
   resources: irq:44 ioport:2018(size=8) ioport:2024(size=4) ioport:2010(size=8) ioport:2020(size=4) ioport:2000(size=16) memory:c1100000-c11007ff memory:c1500000-c150ffff
 *-disk
      description: ATA Disk
      product: MARVELL Raid VD
      physical id: 0
      bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
      logical name: /dev/sdb
      version: MV.R
      serial: d6f015c177ef0010
      size: 931GiB (1TB)
      capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
      configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512
```

I'm properly stuck now - I mounted a USB drive in `/etc/fstab` with no trouble, but this one refuses to play ball. Does anyone have any idea what I can try next?

Comment: I suppose you are meaning Hardware RAID there. So the question is what happens if you try to format (fsck) the partition you created?

Answer (score 0):

Excellently, after posting this question I managed to do it (isn't that always the way?).

For whatever reason cfdisk wasn't partitioning the drives. Using `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb5` sorted the drives out and then I could mount it in fstab.

Thanks to anyone that gave it some thought.